# The Build Output console prints messy codes when upgrade the Android studio to the version of '3.6'

Tags: android, android-studio

It prints messy codes when prints 'Not English' charactors.
 Just like this:
ָ�����õ�Դ�ļ���

And it doesn't work when set this:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```

Is it the newest Android studio's bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the `studio64.exe.vmoptions` file in the AS installation directory and add a line of code: `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`